# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' after idle time

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, authentication

In our web.config we specify a SQL user and password to log into SQL with SQL Authentication and not Windows Authentication.

When deployed to IIS, everything works fine, but when I keep my browser session open for a long time without user interaction I get the error:

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

If this was a SQL timeout error I would expect a different error, but as it only happens after some idle time, I would assume it is related to a timeout.

Is this a SQL timeout error? Is it trying to log into SQL with NT Authority?

Error Message:

> Application Error: SqlException.
>
> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)

Comment: For future readers, sometimes kerberos tickets will cause this.  see https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tspring/2014/06/23/viewing-and-purging-cached-kerberos-tickets/    germane text : List All Cached Kerberos Tickets (GetKerbTix.ps1)
Purge All Kerberos Tickets (PurgeAllKerbTickets.ps1)